# Group Rails attribute errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm attempting to implement a design change which calls for showing errors across several tabs on a page.

I've been validating my model as such: (There are more validations; this is just one example.)

```
validate :has_comment? if: lambda { |r| r.last_step? && r.request_type == :snf_request }

def has_comment?
  errors[:base] << "Request must have at least one comment." if self.comments.blank?
end
```

This works, but obviously all of these error messages are appended to that `errors[:base]` array.

I tried doing something like this:

```
def has_comment?
  errors[:comments_page] << "Request must have at least one comment." if self.comments.blank?
end
```

with the thought that I could call a partial for the error messages, and just pass a `symbol` to it specifying which page of errors it should output.

When I tested this in the `rails console`, I created a new blank `Request` object and retrieved its errors. Typing `r.errors[:base]` gave me validation messages that I had added like the first example, and `r.errors[:comments_page]` gave me messages that I had added in the second example.

This, however, does not work when I go to my application and actually create a blank request. The error messages partial renders, but it's blank. Here is my partial and how I am rendering it for reference.

```
<%= form_for @request, html: { id: "new_request_form", autocomplete: :off } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'snf/shared/error_messages', target: f.object %>
```

And the partial:

```
<% if target.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(target.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% target.errors[:base].each do |msg| %>
        <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**And here is the controller action**

```
def update
  @request = Snf::Request.find(params[:id])
  @request.update_attributes(params[:snf_request])

  if params[:save] == "draft"
    @request.current_step = "draft"
  else
    @request.current_step = @request.steps.last
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @request.save
        if params[:save] == "draft"
          notice = 'snf.requests.message.draft'
        elsif is_new || is_forwarded
          notice = 'snf.requests.message.sent'
        else
          notice = 'snf.requests.message.updated'
        end

    format.html {
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t(notice)
      redirect_to snf_physician_path(current_user)
    }
    format.json {
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t(notice)
      redirect_to snf_physician_path(current_user)
    }
  else
    if params[:forwarded_consult_request]
      format.html {
        @request_types = Snf::RequestType.all
        @physicians = User.physicians_by_specialty
        render action: "forward"
      }
    else
      format.html{
        @request_types = Snf::RequestType.all
        @physicians = User.physicians_by_specialty
        render action: "edit_new"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

I just added the `target.errors[:base]` in there for testing. It normally reads `target.errors.full_messages`.

Am I missing something here? Why does this seem to work in `irb/rails console` but not when applied to the actual application? Is there another, more sane way to do this?

Comment: If the partial is not rendering any HTML it's because `target.errors` is empty. If it's empty you'd likely benefit from showing us where `f` and `f.object` are set in your action.

Comment: Sure, I updated my question to show that.

Comment: Could you provide the controller code where the save is happening?

Comment: **To be clear since you missed it when I requested it:** We need to see where `@request` is having it's `object` saved.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you were asking for. I can provide that, sure, but I don't think that's an issue, since when I change the error messages output back to `target.errors.full_messages.each`, all the errors are present.

Comment: Okay, I added the controller code. Please let me know if there's anything else I missed.